# Open Generics with injected primitive

Tags: dryioc

How can I register an Open Generic type with another open generic and primitive injected in the constructor?
See example below.
In this example, Resolve is throwing "Unable to resolve String as parameter "connectionString"" exception. (you can check live code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/US0BSr))

```
using System;
using DryIoc;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        container.RegisterInstance("some_connection_string", serviceKey: "connectionString");
        container.Register(typeof(Configuration<>), Reuse.Singleton);
        container.Register(typeof (IEntityUpdater<>), typeof (SqlEntityUpdater<>), Reuse.Singleton);

        var p = container.Resolve<IEntityUpdater<EventArgs>>();

        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }   
}

public class Configuration<T> where T : class { }


internal interface IEntityUpdater<in T> where T : class
{
    void Update(T entity);
}

internal class SqlEntityUpdater<T> : IEntityUpdater<T> where T : class
{
    public SqlEntityUpdater(Configuration<T> configuration, string connectionString)
    {
    }

    public void Update(T entity) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `RegisterInstance` is depricated, use `UseInstance`.

Second, the actual problem is that you registering instance with `serviceKey` and nowhere using this key for injection.

So, you either remove the `serviceKey` parameter.

Or, specify the key on injection side:

```
container.Register(typeof(IEntityUpdater<>), typeof(SqlEntityUpdater<>), Reuse.Singleton,
    made: Parameters.Of.Type<string>(serviceKey: "connectionString"));
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, dadhi. Sorry, I don't see how your answer helps me on solving the problem. As you can see on my example, `SqlEntityUpdater` needs two services in the constructor. I'm aware of the `serviceKey` issue but how can I use more than one `Parameters.Of.Type<>` in the `made:` argument?

Comment: Ok, never mind, my bad. I was assuming that you need to specify all arguments. But it seems DryIoc just needs a little help on figuring out some of them. Thanks, once again.